# Как передать любой JSON-ответ от сервера на Node.js БЕЗ Express?

Tags: node.js, веб-сервер, клиент-сервер, fetch

Написал простейший сервер (локалхост).
При переходе по ссылке открывается браузер, он показывает Hello World.
Хочу сделать fetch из HTML-страницы, чтобы приходил JSON-ответ от сервера и расшифровать его и вывести в консоль браузера.
Что написать в теле сервера (БЕЗ Express), чтобы fetch был успешным?
Код сервера:

```html
const http = require('http')
const hostname = '127.0.0.1'
const port = 8080
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.statusCode = 200
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
    res.end('Hello World\n')
})
server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`)
})

// запустить в браузере http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

переход по ссылке в браузере:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код фетча:

```html
const fetchButton = document.getElementById("fetchButton");

fetchButton.onclick = ()=> {
    alert("кнопка нажата")

    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8080/').then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response.json();
        }
        throw new Error('response failed!!')
    }, networkError => console.error(networkError.message)).then(jsonresponse => {
        console.log(JSON.parse(jsonresponse))
    })
}
```

Почему спрашиваю - потому что везде пишут про ЭКспресс и его методы, а мне это пока не надо.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29712051/nodejs-http-post-json-data/29712878

Comment: @entithat вы для реквестов пример пишете, а я спрашиваю респонс. Как правильно описать RESPONSE в теле сервера на ноде, чтобы через fetch через браузер мне выдавало ну сколько-нибудь что-то внятное, кроме бесчисленных ошибок ?

Comment: Ну там же пишет. `res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); res.end(JSON.stringify(OBJ));`

Comment: @entithat заработало! Спасибо вам огромное! День прошёл не зря )))))

Comment: Пожалуйста.....